# How will get content-size if I open remote file via HTTP using fopen

Tags: php, curl, stream, wrapper

So.

```
$f = fopen('http_url_site_com_my_file_ext');
$info = stream_get_meta_data($f);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-get-meta-data.php

as we read in docs, I can find content-lenth in

```
echo $info['wrapper-data'][#] ; // --> Content-length: 438;
```

also

```
echo $info['wrapper_type']; //--> http
```

In my case, I see
cURL instead http

and

```
$info['wrapper-data']['headers']; //empty array
```

So I cann't to get length of responce.

===========
info http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

we can get the response headers such

```
$f = fopen('http_url_site_com_my_file_ext');
var_dump($http_response_header); // --> null.
$data = fread($f, 100);
var_dump($http_response_header); // --> array of all response headers.
```

But it is very very bad for my code. we open a lot of files at the start(if one of them is fault - die())

and then, we read from opened files.

============
QUESTION

1)if I will compile php without "--with-curlwrappers", why this experimental feature is present???
---php 5.4.21 (php-fpm)
---in phpinfo, I see no build option as '--with-curlwrappers'

2)
or how can I get response headers without reading stream

???

please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

Is it mandatory to use fopen instead of cURL?

This example would work with cURL

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $http_url_site_com_my_file_ext);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$r = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($r);
```

Also you can use http_head if HTTP extension is enabled.

Comment: no. extra request. I haven't free time for it. one file = one request.

Comment: also, I open local files to, in future I will use sockets, other protocols.

Comment: and I can use HTTP HEAD method without http extension , useing curl, useing streams, sockets, iven use fopen.

Comment: I don't find another way, I know it. I want find decision in my task.